# Update a column of a table with a column of another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update column from one table to another table of different database.

I searched on stack but found answers for PostgreSQL and SQLite. Those code ain't worked for me properly in SQL Server.

Say,

- D1,D2 are the two different databases
- T1 is the table
- C1,C2,C3 are the columns in `T1`

I want to update like

```
UPDATE T1 
SET D2.T1.C1 = D1.T1.C1
WHERE D2.T1.C2 = D1.T1.C2
```

Everything except the `where` clause works fine.

Here is some code I tried:

```
use DB2
GO

UPDATE TABLE1 
SET COL1 = (SELECT COL1 FROM DB1.dbo.TABLE1) 
WHERE COL2 = DB1.dbo.TABLE1.COL2
```

How shall I write this query?

**Note:** D1 and D2 are identical. Both have the exact same schema. Just the name and data are different. Both databases are on the same server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server supports an update join syntax:

```
UPDATE t1
SET COL1 = t2.COL1
FROM TABLE1 D1.t1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 D2.t2
    ON t1.COL2 = t2.COL2;
```

Actually, your current approach might work, but you should try changing it to this:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 D1.t1
SET COL1 = (SELECT t2.COL1 FROM TABLE2 D2.t2 WHERE T1.COL2 = T2.COL2);
```

Comment: I seen this in a post recently but have a doubt... Why inner join and not a where clause?

Comment: @RitaShroff Every database uses slightly different syntax, it is up to the creators of SQL Server.  In any case, you may try both of my answers and see if either works for you.

Comment: The first version should work and might be the most efficient way to write your update query in SQL Server.

Comment: *"I seen this in a post recently Why inner join and not a where clause?"* second query database portablity it follows SQL standards more i believe, first query for most likley more performance but you will lose database portablity @RitaShroff  MySQL database for example  uses a other syntax order `UPDATE ,,, INNER JOIN .. SET..` . i don't believe the UPDATE join syntax like this is included in SQL standards i could be wrong it could be in the lastest.. Also the SQL standard is just a guideline database vendors can  choose to implement something or not or to add features (dialect) on top of it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yea but I got Error. Multipart identifier D1.dbo.T1.C1 could not be bound. I tried using Inner Join. But I have different database. So the 2nd Line I wrote `SET COL1 = D1.T1.C1` **Note That I have different Database with Same Table and Column Name**

Comment: @RaymondNijland  Yeah I think 2nd Option will work for me.

Comment: @RitaShroff try a  fully quantified co-related update subquery. `UPDATE
 D2.T2.C1
SET D2.T2.C1 = (SELECT D1.T1.C2 FROM D2.T1 WHERE D2.T1.C2 = D1.T1.C2)` then you don't have to use `USE database` first, this method should also work for the first query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The code you just edited is actually 2nd option. But you said _The first version should work and might be the most efficient way to write your update query in SQL Server._ So I tried the 1st one 1st.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 2nd option Worked. Can You please edit your post and remove the inner join option so I can mark it as answer.?

Comment: I won't remove it, but I have edited it to use the database name.  As I already mentioned, update join syntax is probably the most efficient way to write the update in SQL Server, so it should stay here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Okay

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an `INNER JOIN` cause [[image]sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) support Cross-Database Queries, so you can do as:

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.Col1 = T2.Col1
FROM DataBase1.Schema.TableName T1 INNER JOIN DataBase2.Schema.TableName T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID;
```

Please, visit and read **[`Cross-Database Queries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/cross-database-queries?view=sql-server-2017)**.

Answer (score 0):

Or `update tableName set column Name = (select columnName from second table where 1=1)  i.e condition is either true or false optional though`